# How to get an event or callback in my win form app for change in a windows service status

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, service

I have created a WinForm app on .net 4.0 using the a sdk provided by my company. In the app I am checking for the state of service which is a part of the sdk(it runs when I install the sdk.)
I am using Service Controller Class to check for its state. something like this.

```
private string CheckSDKService()
    {
        ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("MyService");

        switch (sc.Status)
        {
            case ServiceControllerStatus.Running:
                return "Running";
            case ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped:
                return "Stopped";
            default:
                return "Status Changing";
        }
    }
```

Now the problem is that I do not want to keep calling this and polling periodically for the status.  Is there any way i can get some kind of notification whenever service stops. I have already looked at WMI and couldn't understand how to use it in WinForm c# app. There is also NotifyServiceStatusChange but its in c++ and i dont want to use P\Invoke or COM. This app is a sample app for the sdk and i dont want to complicate it.

Comment: Just use polling. The overhead should not be to bad if you keep interval resonable. What is the reason for monitoring?

Comment: Poll it in a background worker or in another thread

Comment: **`i dont want to use P\Invoke or COM`** - If you keep thinking like this, you **will never have powerful application**. You have to understand that **PInvoke** is just a way to communicate to the underlying/native API which is `Win32`, it's the fundamental API of `Windows`, using native API is a **must-do** thing in some cases to solve problems out. **it's not something hacky or tricky**, **it's how it should be done**.

Comment: And i guess thats why the downvote?? sometime you have to work with constraint.. here i am trying to create a sample application for my sdk and i dont want to use p\Invoke.  there are various reason for that, but not understanding pInvoke or not creating a powerful application is not one of them.

Comment: Avijeet can share code to handle callback from the services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something very similar to the previous comments. I wrote a class which has an event that you are able to subscribe to. I have this running on a worker thread, and poll every couple of minutes. It's implemented exactly how you have, except instead of returning it fires off events. You can then just listen to this class and do whatever it is your program requires :)

Comment: Thanks i will go for it. I thought may be there is some other clever way of doing it.

Comment: Nope, not to my knowledge. That's the best way to do it! Good luck!

Comment: Hi glen I have similar requirement can you share code how to implement it